# How to use autofs to mount an NFS share on IPA server

Tags: centos7, nfs, freeipa

I have an IPA Server and client set up, with NFS and autofs installed on both. Whenever I make a user with ipa user-add, and then I switch to that user, IPA creates a home directory for that user and displays `Creating home directory for user`. I want to make it so autofs sets up the home directory instead, so that IPA does not need to. My IPA server also acts as an NFS server and I added `/home` into my `/etc/exports` and pointed it to my client machine. My IPA client serves as my NFS client and it has `/home` mounted on `/mnt/nfs/home`. On my client I went into /etc/auto.master and added a line /home   /etc/auto.misc. Then I added onto /etc/auto.misc with the line: 
`*  -fstype=nfs    :nameofserver.example.home:/mnt/nfs/home`. After all that, I restarted autofs and tried making a user but when I switch to the user now I get the message `warning: cannot change directory to /home/user: No such file or directory` What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The IPA configuration of autofs make that the user home is mounted not the root of user home. That means in your case that the autofs is trying to mount /mnt/nfs/home/newuser.

AFAIK they are no official workaround with this chicken/egg problems. Free-ipa is currently working on a hook/callback systeme that is supposed to provide a solution to that old and well know "problematic".

Since this update was'nt available yet, the only know way is to setup a cron script that make call to the LDAP service of the IDM server and create the new home. But no one seens to have release a code to do so.

Here is the bash script I have made for this purpose. I ran it in a cron set to each minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash
TIMEFILE=/root/scripts/data/ldap_last_check.txt
LASTTIME=$(cat $TIMEFILE)
CURRENTTIME=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ)
echo $LASTTIME
NEWUSERLIST=$(/usr/bin/ldapsearch -LLL -x  -h localhost -b "cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=domain,dc=com" "(createTimestamp>=$LASTTIME)" uid)
UID_REGEX="^uid:"

mount filesrv:/srv/idmhome /mnt/idmhome
OLDUSERLIST=$(ls -1 /mnt/idmhome)


while read -r i_line; do
    HOME_EXIST=false
    if [[ $i_line =~ $UID_REGEX ]]; then
        TMPUSER="$(echo $i_line | awk '{print $NF}')"
        while read -r j_line; do
            if [[ $TMPUSER = $j_line ]]; then
                HOME_EXIST=true
            fi
            if [[ $TMPUSER = "admin" ]]; then
                HOME_EXIST=true
            fi
        done <<< "$OLDUSERLIST"
        if ! $HOME_EXIST; then         
            mkdir /mnt/idmhome/$TMPUSER
            cp /etc/skel/.* /mnt/idmhome/admin/
            chown -R $TMPUSER:$TMPUSER /mnt/idmhome/$TMPUSER/
            ls -lah /mnt/idmhome/$TMPUSER
        fi
    fi

done <<< "$NEWUSERLIST"

umount /mnt/idmhome
echo $CURRENTTIME > $TIMEFILE
```

My setup is a little bit different than your, my nfs server is'nt on the same server as my IDM. You just have to comment the mount/umount line and change path to yours and it's should work fine.

consider to make a similar code to erase/archive deleted account.